# SAS: Adding aggregated data to same dataset

Tags: sas

I'm migrating from SPSS to SAS.
I need to compute the sum of variable *varX*, separately by groups of variables *varA varB*, and add it as a new variable *sumX* to the same dataset.

In SPSS this is implemented easily with *aggregate*:

```
aggregate outfile *
/break varA varB
/SUMvarX = sum(varX).
```

can this be done in SAS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but the *best* way depends on your data.

For a typical use case, the `PROC MEANS` solution is what I'd recommend.  It's not the fastest, but it gets the job done, and it has a lot lower opportunity of error - you're not really doing anything except match-merging afterwards.

Use the `class` statement instead of `by` in most cases; it shouldn't make much of a difference, but it's the purpose of `class`.  `by` runs the analysis separately for each value of those variables; `class` runs one analysis grouping by all of those variables.  It is more flexible and doesn't require a sorted dataset (though you would have to sort anyway for the later merge).  `class` also lets you do multiple combinations - not just the `nway` combination you ask for here, but if you want it grouped just by `a`, just by `b`, and by `a*b`, you can get that (with `class` and `types`).

```
proc means data=have;
  class a b;
  var x;
  output out=summary sum(x)=;
run;

data want;
  merge have summary;
  by a b;
run;
```

The DoW loop covered in Kermit's answer is a reasonable data step option also, though more risky in terms of programmer error; I'd use it only in particular cases where the dataset is very very large - more than fits in memory *in summary size* large - and performance was important.

If the data fits in memory, you can also use a hash table to do the summary, and that's what I'd do if the summary dataset fit comfortably in memory.  This is too long for an answer here, but [Data Aggregation using Hash Object](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/2000-2015.pdf) is a good start for how to do that.  Basically, you use a [hash table](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/n1b4cbtmb049xtn1vh9x4waiioz4.htm) to store the results of the summary (not the raw data), adding to it with each row, and then output the hash table at the end.  A bit faster than the DoW loop, but slightly memory constrained (although if you used SPSS, you're much more memory constrained than this!).  Also very easy to handle multiple combinations.

Another "programmer easy" way to do it is with SQL.

```
proc sql;
  create want as
   select *, sum(x) as sum_x
    from have
    group by a,b
  ;
quit;
```

This is not standard SQL, but SAS manages it - basically it does the two step process of the `proc means` and the merge, in one step.  I like this in some ways (because it skips the intermediate dataset, even if it does actually make this dataset in the util folder, just cleans up for you automatically) and dislike it in others (it's not standard SQL so it will confuse people, and it leaves a note in the log - only a note, so not a big deal, but still).

---

Adding a note about SPSS -> SAS thinking.  One of the bigger differences you'll see going from SPSS to SAS is that, in SPSS, you have one dataset, and you do stuff to it (mostly).  You could save it as a different dataset, but you mostly don't until the end - all of your work really is just editing one dataset, in memory.

In SAS, you read datasets from disk and do stuff and then write them out, and if you're doing anything that is at the dataset level (like a summary), you mostly will do it separately and then recombine with the data in a later step.  As such, it's very, very common to have lots of datasets - a program I just ran probably has a thousand.  Not kidding!  Don't worry about random temporary datasets being produced - it doesn't mean your code is not efficient.  It's just how SAS works.  There are times where you do have to be careful about it - like you have 150GB datasets or something - but if you're working with 5000 rows with 150 variables, your dataset is so small you could write it a thousand times without noticing a meaningful difference to your code execution time.

The big benefit to this style is that you have different datasets for each step, so if you go back and want to rerun part of your code, you can safely - knowing the predecessor dataset still exists, without having to rerun *all* of your code.  It also lets you debug really easily since you can see each of the component parts.

It's a tradeoff for sure, because it does mean it takes a little longer to run the code, but in the modern day CPUs are really really fast, and so are SSDs - it's just not necessary to write code that stays all in one data step or runs entirely in memory.  The tradeoff is that you get the ability to do crazy large amounts of things that couldn't possibly fit in memory, work with massive datasets, etc. - only constrained by *disk*, which is usually in far greater supply.  It's a tradeoff worth making in many cases.  When it's possible to do something in a PROC, do so, even when that means it costs a tiny bit of time at the end to re-merge it - the PROCs are what you're paying SAS the big bucks for, they are easy to use, well tested, and fast at what they do.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response and bonus SPSS-SAS explanation.
I can already understand it has a very different frame-of-thinking.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I found a way of doing that.
First, you produce the summing varables:

```
proc means data= <dataset> noprint nway;
    by  varA varB;
    var varX;
    output out=<TEMPdataset> sum = SUMvarX;
run;
```

then you merge the two datasets:

```
DATA <dataset>;
   MERGE <TEMPdataset> <dataset>;
   BY varA varB;
run;
```

This seems to work, although an extra dataset and several extra variables are formed in the process.
There are probably more efficient ways of doing it...

Comment: This is the typical way you would do something like this. It's not the fastest-as-in-CPU-time method, but it's the fastest-as-in-programmer-time method, and what I'd recommend, over DoW and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of [DoW Loop](https://sasnrd.com/sas-dow-loop-example/)?

```
*-- Create synthetic data --*
data have;
varA=2; varB=4; varX=21; output;
varA=4; varB=6; varX=32; output;
varA=5; varB=8; varX=83; output;
varA=4; varB=3; varX=78; output;
varA=4; varB=8; varX=72; output;
varA=2; varB=4; varX=72; output;
run;

proc sort data=have; by varA varB; quit;

varA varB varX
 2    4    21
 2    4    72
 4    3    78
 4    6    32
 4    8    72
 5    8    83
```

```
data stage1;
set have;
by varA varB;
if first.varB then group_number+1;
run;

data want;
do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.group_number);
    set stage1;
    by group_number;
    SUMvarX=sum(SUMvarX, varX);
end;

do until (last.group_number);
    set stage1;
    by group_number;
    output;
end;

drop group_number;
run;
```

```
varA varB varX SUMvarX
 2    4    21     93
 2    4    72     93
 4    3    78     78
 4    6    32     32
 4    8    72     72
 5    8    83     83
```